# Linux command to Cut everything after certain word in a file and export to another file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a input file like this in filenames.txt file

```
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-04-01.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-04-08.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-04-15.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-04-22.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-04-29.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-06.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-13.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-06.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-13.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-20.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-27.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-03.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-08.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-16.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-22.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-29.csv
```

**I want to cut everything after ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-04-29.csv and export to another file**

I have tried this

```
sed 's,.*wordpattern \(.\),\1,' /path/filenames.txt > path/Filenames_Plan_Amt.txt



sed 's,.*ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-04-29.csv \(.\),\1,' SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/Filenames.txt > SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/Filenames_Plan_Amt.txt
```

But doesn't seem to be working!

I want output file having

```
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-06.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-13.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-06.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-13.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-20.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-05-27.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-03.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-08.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-16.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-22.csv
SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/ActivationFlowPrepaid/Archive/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-06-29.csv
```

Please guide me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the lines from the first line to the line containing `2019-04-29`, use

```
sed '1,/2019-04-29/d' file > newfile
```

Comment: Hello! tried it! I need to cut it from input not just copy from input, input file still has all the files.

Comment: You can use `sed -i '1,/2019-04-29/d' file` to edit the file in-place with GNU `sed` or `sed -i '' '1,/2019-04-29/d' file` with BSD `sed`.

Comment: sed '1,/2019-04-29/d' file > newfile | new file is having all the names after '2019-04-29', which is good!

sed -i '1,/2019-04-29/d' file | file leaving with names after '2019-04-29'
whilst i need to have before '2019-04-29' which then serves the purpose!

Comment: You need two commands for that: `sed '1,/2019-04-29/d' file > newfile; sed -i 's/1,/2019-04-29/!d' file` This would leave line 1 until the line containing `2019-04-29` in `file`.

Comment: yes Freddy that's what i did previously, now both the files have the same filenames!

Comment: perfect, sorry i haven't seen the negation!

Comment: perfect, sorry i haven't seen the negation!

Answer (score 1):

It will be briefer with awk:

```
awk 'f;/ActivationFlowPrepaidActs_2019-04-29.csv/{f=1}' input
```

Comment: Hello! tried it! I need to cut it from input not just copy from input.  input file still has all the files.